# Is there any way to link two Cron Jobs in OpenShift

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-cronjob

everyone!
Is there any way to link two Cron Jobs in OpenShift? I have two Cron Jobs. The first one makes a .tar archive from some data. And the second one should operate with this archive. Can I add some condition to the second Cron Job, to make it run only if the first one has finished? The first Cron Job can run from several seconds to several hours, so it is not very comfortable to guess certain time interval, to be sure that it is completed.
Will be thankful for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. Share the archive file via persist volume, and in the second job readiness probe to check if the jar file exists, then make decision to go ahead or abort for next check, archive the archive file to other location after finish.
2. With Kubernetes API to schedule the second job in the first job